# scrolltop detecting scrolling multiple times

Tags: javascript, events, scroll, scrolltop

Im using the following example to detect the direction of scrolling . However, it seems to operate on every scroll movement. Is there any way of getting it to operate only when the direction changes?

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(event){
   var st = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (st > lastScrollTop){
       // downscroll code
   } else {
      // upscroll code
   }
   lastScrollTop = st;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure.  Just use a placeholder variable that keeps track of the last direction that was travelled, then return false if it is a match.

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var lastDirection = "";
$(window).scroll(function (event) {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (st > lastScrollTop) {
        lastScrollTop = st;
        if (lastDirection === 'down') return false;
        // downscroll code
        console.log("scrolling down");
        lastDirection = 'down';
    } else {
        lastScrollTop = st;
        if (lastDirection === 'up') return false;
        // upscroll code
        console.log("scrolling up");
        lastDirection = 'up';
    }

});
```

Comment: Hi, it still seems to fire multiple times, for each scroll change. Im trying to get it to only fire when the direction changes. I think there must be an error in the code with lastDirection? Should it copy the lastScrollTop variable?

Comment: I admittedly did not try the code.  Let me plug it into a fiddle right quick and see what could be happening.

Comment: Ah, fixed it.  The problem was that lastDirection was getting re-initialized every iteration because it was defined in the lambda function.  It would be best to define it in the same scope that lastScrollTop is defined.  See my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vupzbvzw/3/)

Comment: Also, unfortunately the lastScrollTop needs to be put inside the if statements, otherwise it also won't update unless the direction changes.